# UICollectionView Disappear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm quite new to Swift. My problem is that my `UICollectionView` is disappearing.
In `Xcode`, it shows that everything is in place, but when I launch on a simulator or a device it disappears only left with the Navigation Bar and the Tab Bar.

Does anyone know what caused this or how to solve this?
Cheers!

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

> class User: UICollectionViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! UserHeaderView
    header.userEmail.text = PFUser.current()!.email
    header.userChosenName.text = PFUser.current()!.object(forKey: "nickname") as? String
    header.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = header.profilePicture.frame.size.width/2
    header.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
    let query = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "profilePicture") as! PFFile
    query.getDataInBackground { (image, error) in
        if error == nil {
        header.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: image!)
        }
        else {
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Something's Wrong...")
        }
    }
    return header
}
```

Comment: share your code here then we can thnk about problem

Comment: Did you set auto layout for each item of your design ??

Comment: you are returning 0 items in numberOfItemsInSection and in numberOfSections this is why you dont have any cells showing up

Comment: you will have return some number from numberOfItemsInSection and numberOfSections then you will be able to see cells or headerView

Comment: @MaheshDangar Here is my code, would you please have a look. Cheers!

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi Thank you for replying. I've change both 0s to 1 but the app just crashed. What integer should I be inserting? Cheers!

Comment: Thank you all for those who spend the time and effort to help me, its such a great community here. Again, thanks a lot. Have a g'day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the generated class and you have the number of sections 0 and number of rows 0 you have to change those based the count you want them to show

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // The number of sections you have to provide 
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Number of Items in this section at least it should be 1
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind:  UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! UserHeaderView
    header.userEmail.text = PFUser.current()!.email
    header.userChosenName.text = PFUser.current()!.object(forKey: "nickname") as? String
    header.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = header.profilePicture.frame.size.width/2
header.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
   let query = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "profilePicture") as! PFFile
query.getDataInBackground { (image, error) in
    if error == nil {
    header.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: image!)
    }
    else {
        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Something's Wrong...")
    }
}
    return header
}
```

**Edit:**
You should have a cellForItemAt indexPath func else app will crash. here is an example of the function

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // this will return an empty cell where you're app will not crash
    // but you have to create a cell and populate some data to the cell
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. I've changed the integers to 1 as you instructed, however the app just crashed when I open the view. REASON: the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016>. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @zhangallan see the edited there is the missing function you have and read some more about it how to populate

Comment: Solved it!! Thanks a lot for you time and effort. I do need more experience and a lot more to learn. But thanks again and have a g'day!